# redis keys command delete data but scan command does not

Tags: redis

```
redis-cli -s /data/redis/redis.sock --scan --pattern "*abcd|6128*" | xargs -L 100 redis-cli -s /data/redis/redis.sock DEL
```

above command is not deleting adta from redis and giving following output

```
(integer) 0
```

While the keys command works perfectly

```
 redis-cli -s /data/redis/redis.sock KEYS 'abcd|6291*' | xargs redis-cli -s /data/redis/redis.sock DEL;
```

Is there is something wrong i am doing

Answer (score 1):

Try `xargs` with `-L 1` instead. Worked for me.

`redis-cli -s /data/redis/redis.sock --scan --pattern "*abcd|6128*" | xargs -L 1 redis-cli -s /data/redis/redis.sock DEL`

BTW, `KEYS` should be avoided in production environments as it is a blocking command.

Answer (score -1):

scan only applies to some keys (by default on 10 keys per iteration). It returns an offset to continuesly run scan until you reach offset 0. Then you have sampled all keys. More details are in the documentation: http://redis.io/commands/scan

Keys on the other hand samples all keys in the db in one pass. It is also blocking due to redises single threaded architecture which might be bad for performance of other clients.